# The difference of pseudo-inverse between SciPy and Numpy

Tags: matrix, numpy, scipy

I found that there're two versions of `pinv()` function, which calculates the pseudo-inverse of a matrix in `Scipy` and `numpy`, the documents can be viewed at:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pinv.html

The problem is that I have a 50000*5000 matrix, when using `scipy.linalg.pinv`, it costs me more than 20GB of memory. But when I use `numpy.linalg.pinv`, only less than 1GB of memory is used..

I was wondering why `numpy` and `scipy` both have a `pinv` under different implemention. And why their performances are so different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't speak as to why there are implementations in both scipy and numpy, but I can explain why the behaviour is different.

`numpy.linalg.pinv` approximates the Moore-Penrose psuedo inverse using an SVD (the lapack method `dgesdd` to be precise), whereas `scipy.linalg.pinv` solves a model linear system in the least squares sense to approximate the pseudo inverse (using `dgelss`). This is why their performance is different. I would expect the overall accuracy of the resulting pseudo inverse estimates to be somewhat different as well.

You might find that `scipy.linalg.pinv2` performs more similarly to  `numpy.linalg.pinv`, as it too uses an SVD method, rather than a least sqaures approximation.

Comment: "better" is a very subjective term. Only you know what you need the pseudo inverse for in the first place. Presumably you also have criteria about the performance and numerical stability of your algorithms. Whichever one is "better" is the one which best satisfies your criteria.